# Python generate all combinations of directions including diagonals in 3 dimensions

Tags: python

I want to generate all directions from a point in a 3D grid, but I can't quite get my head around the next bit. For the record it's all stored in a single list, so I need some maths to calculate where the next point will be.

I only really need 3 calculations to calculate any of the 26 or so different directions (up, up left, up left forwards, up left backwards, up right, up right forwards, etc), so I decided to work with X, Y, Z, then split them into up/down left/right etc, to then get the correct number to add or subtract. Generating this list to get the maths working however, seems to be the hard bit.

```
direction_combinations = 'X Y Z XY XZ YZ XYZ'.split()
direction_group = {}
direction_group['X'] = 'LR'
direction_group['Y'] = 'UD'
direction_group['Z'] = 'FB'
```

So basically, using the below code, this is the kind of stuff I'd like it to do, but obviously not have it hard coded. I could do it in a hacky way, but I imagine there's something really simple I'm missing here.

```
#Earlier part of the code to get this bit working
#I've also calculated the edges but it's not needed until after I've got this bit working
grid_size = 4
direction_maths = {}
direction_maths['U'] = pow(grid_size, 2)
direction_maths['R'] = 1
direction_maths['F'] = grid_size
direction_maths['D'] = -direction_maths['U']
direction_maths['L'] = -direction_maths['R']
direction_maths['B'] = -direction_maths['F']



#Bit to get working
starting_point = 25
current_direction = 'Y'

possible_directions = [direction_group[i] for i in list(current_direction)]
for y in list(possible_directions[0]):
    print starting_point + direction_maths[y]
# 41 and 9 are adjacent on the Y axis


current_direction = 'XYZ'

possible_directions = [direction_group[i] for i in list(current_direction)]
for x in list(possible_directions[0]):
    for y in list(possible_directions[1]):
        for z in list(possible_directions[2]):
            print starting_point + direction_maths[x] + direction_maths[y] + direction_maths[z]
# 44, 36, 12, 4, 46, 38, 14 and 6 are all adjacent on the corner diagonals
```

Here's a general idea of how the grid looks with the list indexes (using 4x4x4 as an example):

```
        ________________
       / 0 / 1 / 2 / 3 /
      /___/___/___/___/
     / 4 / 5 / 6 / 7 /
    /___/___/___/___/
   / 8 / 9 /10 /11 /
  /___/___/___/___/
 /12 /13 /14 /15 /
/___/___/___/___/
        ________________
       /16 /17 /18 /19 /
      /___/___/___/___/
     /20 /21 /22 /23 /
    /___/___/___/___/
   /24 /25 /26 /27 /
  /___/___/___/___/
 /28 /29 /30 /31 /
/___/___/___/___/
        ________________
       /32 /33 /34 /35 /
      /___/___/___/___/
     /36 /37 /38 /39 /
    /___/___/___/___/
   /40 /41 /42 /43 /
  /___/___/___/___/
 /44 /45 /46 /47 /
/___/___/___/___/
        ________________
       /48 /49 /50 /51 /
      /___/___/___/___/
     /52 /53 /54 /55 /
    /___/___/___/___/
   /56 /57 /58 /59 /
  /___/___/___/___/
 /60 /61 /62 /63 /
/___/___/___/___/
```

Edit: Using the answers mixed with what I posted originally (wanted to avoid converting to and from 3D points if possible), this is what I ended up with to count the number of complete rows :)

```
def build_directions():

    direction_group = {}
    direction_group['X'] = 'LR'
    direction_group['Y'] = 'UD'
    direction_group['Z'] = 'FB'
    direction_group[' '] = ' '

    #Come up with all possible directions
    all_directions = set()
    for x in [' ', 'X']:
        for y in [' ', 'Y']:
            for z in [' ', 'Z']:
                x_directions = list(direction_group[x])
                y_directions = list(direction_group[y])
                z_directions = list(direction_group[z])
                for i in x_directions:
                    for j in y_directions:
                        for k in z_directions:
                            all_directions.add((i+j+k).replace(' ', ''))

    #Narrow list down to remove any opposite directions
    some_directions = all_directions
    opposite_direction = all_directions.copy()
    for i in all_directions:
        if i in opposite_direction:
            new_direction = ''
            for j in list(i):
                for k in direction_group.values():
                    if j in k:
                        new_direction += k.replace(j, '')
            opposite_direction.remove(new_direction)
    return opposite_direction


class CheckGrid(object):

    def __init__(self, grid_data):

        self.grid_data = grid_data
        self.grid_size = calculate_grid_size(self.grid_data)
        self.grid_size_squared = pow(grid_size, 2)
        self.grid_size_cubed = len(grid_data)

        self.direction_edges = {}
        self.direction_edges['U'] = range(self.grid_size_squared)
        self.direction_edges['D'] = range(self.grid_size_squared*(self.grid_size-1), self.grid_size_squared*self.grid_size)
        self.direction_edges['R'] = [i*self.grid_size+self.grid_size-1 for i in range(self.grid_size_squared)]
        self.direction_edges['L'] = [i*self.grid_size for i in range(self.grid_size_squared)]
        self.direction_edges['F'] = [i*self.grid_size_squared+j+self.grid_size_squared-self.grid_size for i in range(self.grid_size) for j in range(self.grid_size)]
        self.direction_edges['B'] = [i*self.grid_size_squared+j for i in range(self.grid_size) for j in range(self.grid_size)]
        self.direction_edges[' '] = []

        self.direction_maths = {}
        self.direction_maths['D'] = pow(self.grid_size, 2)
        self.direction_maths['R'] = 1
        self.direction_maths['F'] = self.grid_size
        self.direction_maths['U'] = -self.direction_maths['D']
        self.direction_maths['L'] = -self.direction_maths['R']
        self.direction_maths['B'] = -self.direction_maths['F']
        self.direction_maths[' '] = 0


    def points(self):

        total_points = defaultdict(int)
        opposite_directions = build_directions()
        all_matches = set()

        #Loop through each point
        for starting_point in range(len(self.grid_data)):

            current_player = self.grid_data[starting_point]

            if current_player:

                for i in opposite_directions:

                    #Get a list of directions and calculate movement amount
                    possible_directions = [list(i)]
                    possible_directions += [[j.replace(i, '') for i in possible_directions[0] for j in direction_group.values() if i in j]]
                    direction_movement = sum(self.direction_maths[j] for j in possible_directions[0])

                    #Build list of invalid directions
                    invalid_directions = [[self.direction_edges[j] for j in possible_directions[k]] for k in (0, 1)]
                    invalid_directions = [[item for sublist in j for item in sublist] for j in invalid_directions]

                    num_matches = 1
                    list_match = [starting_point]

                    #Use two loops for the opposite directions
                    for j in (0, 1):

                        current_point = starting_point

                        while current_point not in invalid_directions[j]:
                            current_point += direction_movement*int('-'[:j]+'1')
                            if self.grid_data[current_point] == current_player:
                                num_matches += 1
                                list_match.append(current_point)
                            else:
                                break

                    #Add a point if enough matches
                    if num_matches == self.grid_size:

                        list_match = tuple(sorted(list_match))
                        if list_match not in all_matches:
                            all_matches.add(list_match)
                            total_points[current_player] += 1


        return total_points
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run, and it's hard to understand what you're trying to do. "All directions from a point in a 3D grid." should be clarified to start with -- how do you get to '27 or so different directiosn' from that?

Comment: Updated the question with a preview grid, what I mean is if you take 37, the first points of the different directions are 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 24, 25, 26, 32, 33, 34, 36, 38, 40, 41, 42, 48, 49, 50, 52, 53, 54, 56, 57, and 58 :P   I have the maths to calculate how to get to each of those from 37, just not the code to use that maths

Comment: If you treat X, Y, and Z as independent numbers, they can each be either -1, 0, or 1. Just generate every combination of those and throw the trivial [0,0,0] direction out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make thinks unnecessary complicated. Do not describe a point in 3 dimensions with 1 number - 3 coordinates means 3 numbers.

Should be something like this:

```
numb = 37
cube_size = 4

# convert to x - y - z
start = [0, 0, 0]

start[2] = numb / cube_size ** 2
numb = numb % cube_size ** 2
start[1] = numb / cube_size
start[0] = numb % cube_size


for x in [-1, 0, 1]:
    current_x = start[0] + x
    for y in [-1, 0, 1]:
        current_y = start[1] + y
        for z in [-1, 0, 1]:
            current_z = start[2] + z

            #reconvert
            convert = current_x + current_y * cube_size + current_z * cube_size ** 2
            print("x: " + str(current_x) + " y: " + str(current_y) + " z: " + str(current_z) + " => " + str(convert))
```

Simply generate your x/y/z-coordinate, then run all possibilities of add -1/0/1 to these coordinates and re-convert to your number in the grid.

Comment: `for x in [-1, 0, 1]:` is simpler

Comment: And there's an 'in in' for the x pivot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea, I kinda merged your idea with mine and got it working without converting it to 3D (didn't want to take the easy way out haha) :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's basically the same thing that @AnnoSielder did, but makes use of itertools to reduce the amount of code.

```
from itertools import product

# Get a list of all 26 possible ways to move from a given coordinate in a 3 coordinate system.
base_deltas = filter(lambda point: not all(axis ==0 for axis in point), list(product([-1, 0, 1], repeat=3)))
# Define your max axis length or your grid size
grid_size = 4

# Simple function that applys the deltas to the given coordinate and returns you the list.
def apply_deltas(deltas, coordinate):
    return [
        (coordinate[0]+x, coordinate[1]+y, coordinate[2]+z)
        for x, y, z in deltas
    ]

# This will determine whether the point is out of bounds for the given grid
is_out_of_bounds = lambda point: all(0 <= axis < grid_size for axis in point)

# Define your point, in this case it's block #27 in your example
coordinate = [3, 2, 1]

# Apply the deltas, then filter using the is_out_of_bounds lambda
directions = filter(is_out_of_bounds, apply_deltas(base_deltas, coordinate))

# directions is now the list of 17 coordinates that you could move to.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I don't really know lambda so it's useful seeing it work on something simple, this way seems extremely clean :)

Comment: lambdas can be cool, but they can also get you in trouble. If you're doing some complex/funky stuff in it, just make it a function and use that instead.

Comment: that's a nice way of using lambda. Thanks for showing how less lines you need using Python :).